# Linking one view to another

Tags: views, panels

Here is my scenario - I have populated my content in a panel which consists of 3 views. Each view has a set of documents. 
At the bottom of the page (panel page), I want to add a link which when clicked will take me to another view page populated with all documents from the caller node.  I'm very new to drupal and not able to figure out how to do it.

Please put in your suggestions on how I can do this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What controls the documents shown in the initial caller views? Is it a list of IDs, certain Taxonomy, some custom field, etc?

This is important as it will control how the view page lists the documents you want from the caller view.

If the initial view was displaying documents based on any option that was not ID, then you could easily create a link in the footer and include a parameter. The link should go to the URL of the View Page and include the arguments needed to filter the results shown on the page. It would look something like this:

http://www.example.com/documents/all?argumentname_here=[thiswouldbeatoken]

The token would be the value of the category, taxonomy, etc. that you used in the initial view.

The view page would need to be setup to not use AJAX, so it can use the URL arguments, and should have an exposed filter matching the filter of the caller view (you could then hide this with CSS so it can't be changed later, but let's leave it alone for now).

If you need help figuring out what the URL should look like, try filtering the View Page and clicking Apply and looking at the structure in the URL then mimic this in your initial caller view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: node id is the context that controls the documents being displayed in the initial view. Currently I added a new view to the panel page and put up a link there(using Global: Custom Text field) and pointed it to the 2nd view. However, the second view doesn't get populated (I used context as content id here also).

Comment: If you are using a NID then you should be able to first change the contextual filter on the View Page to Raw Value from URL and change the path component to match where the ID is placed in the custom URL you have made in the initial view. 

So your URL in the first view would look like http://www.example.com/view-page/nidhere and the contextual path component would be 2.

Comment: I sort of understand this now - in the first panel, I created a new view with contextual filter nid and in the footer section, added a global text and added a link which looks like newview/[nid].  In page manager, I added the new view to a panel. Now my problem is how to make sure that new view is loaded in this url.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that!